# changing directories in python - string not recognized

Tags: python, json

I am learning python and one of the operations I am trying to complete is to change directories. I am storing directory names in a dictionary and then trying to access these directories as follows :

Creating the directories :

```
for i in range(length):
    try:
        original_umask = os.umask(0)
        os.makedirs(item_dict[i], 0755)
    finally:
        os.umask(original_umask)
for i in range (length):
    os.chdir(item_dict[i])
```

This is working. However when I try to do further processing later by accessing these directories I run into the following error :

```
osdir = os.getcwd()
print " current working directory is "  + osdir //works correctly
for i in range (length):
    os.chdir((item_dict[i])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\actions.py", line 40, in <module>
    os.chdir((item_dict[i]))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'd-025c49f7-116e-4ad1-909e-13cc59b03dc3/'
```

Here 025c49f7-116e-4ad1-909e-13cc59b03dc3/ is the directory name . The same code works earlier as indicated. Any pointers ?

Comment: Why is there an extra `(` in `os.chdir((item_dict[i])` in second code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.chdir()` changes the current directory for the remainder of the Python script. You are probably better off not changing directories at all, and manipulating files in directories using relative paths.

In other words,

```
os.mkdir('a')
os.chdir('a')
os.mkdir('b')
os.chdir('b')
```

ends up creating `a/b` and leaving you inside this directory; attempting to `os.chdir('b')` again fails, because there is no `b` *inside* this directory - you only just created it, so it is obviously empty.

I'm guessing you wanted to create `a` and `b` as subdirectories of the current directory, not the latter inside the former. Not doing `os.chdir('a')` after creating `a` obviously fixes this; and more generally, unless you specifically want to recursively create a deep sequence of nested directories, there is rarely a need for your programs to switch their working directory.

Needless to say,

```
os.chdir('a')
newfile = open('c', 'w')
```

can be rephrased without changing the working directory;

```
newfile = open(os.path.join(['a', 'c']), 'w')
```

where in this trivial case `open('a/c', 'w')` works as well; but if you do nontrivial processing where directory names and/or file names are in variables, you need to know about the more general `os.path.join()` syntax.

Comment: If you want the `chdir` to see that the directory was successfuly created and can be entered, you can then switch back to the parent directory with `chdir('..')`; but this will do the wrong thing in some corner cases, so I will repeat my advice to avoid `chdir` whenever you can.